# Set BrokeredMessage ContentType in ServiceBus output

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-stream-analytics

I select and send data inside a stream analytics job to a ServiceBus output.

Is it possible to set properties like `ContentType` or `Label` for the resulting BrokeredMessage?

Comment: Currently these properties are not settable, but we will be considering doing this in future. Thanks,
Chetan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently these properties are not settable/readable, but Microsoft will be considering doing this in future.

Here is an open user voice feature request about this: [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics/suggestions/15025632-allow-to-read-write-event-data-properties-from-to)